# dynamic text box dropdown clone

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to create  dynamic text boxes, but i'm having trouble basing them of a clone

essentially what i am trying to do is create a certain amount of text boxes based on the amount of options in a combo box. 5 values in a

```
var optionValues = [];

$('#fieldnameclone option').each(function() {
    optionValues.push($(this).val());
});
optionValues.shift();


var optionspacing="";
    jQuery.each(optionValues, function(i, val) {
      optionspacing += val + ":<br />";
    });
var insfldnms = $("<div id =insertfieldname></section>").html(optionspacing);


var n = $("#fieldname option").length;// get amount of options in dropdownt box


var $frm2 = $("<form id=insertform class=form2></form>");// creates a form
$frm2.append(tblNmClnSrch,fldnmCln,insfldnms);// adds the field and name clones to the form

for(var i = 0; i < n-1; i++) 
{   
        $('<input /></br>', {id: "valueid" + i,name: "name" + i}).appendTo($frm2);

}

var btninsert = $("<input id=inserthbtn type=button value=Submit></input>");
$(btninsert).appendTo($frm2);
$( "#reports3" ).empty();
$("#reports3").append($frm2);
```

not sure where i am going wrong, any help would be awesome

html for fieldname

```
var txt3 = $("<section id =fieldname></section>").text("Text.");
```

fieldname combo box is generated using getjson, that part works fine, so there are elements in the dropdown box

Comment: What about your code is not working as expected?

Comment: so when i run thif the text boxes dont apear,` var btninsert = $("<input id=inserthbtn type=button value=Submit></input>");
 $(btninsert).appendTo($frm2);
 $( "#reports3" ).empty();
 $("#reports3").append($frm2);`

Comment: Can you show your html?

Comment: just eddited the post

Comment: You still havent shown the HTML for `#fieldname`. Also *when* is this supposed to happen, when you change `#fieldname`?

Comment: Also, what is this about `"<div id =insertfieldname></section>"`? Its not clear what `optionspacing` is doing or how it is related to this question'

Comment: i think ive asked this in one big go, sorry il try and split this up and rephrase it